# How to run ASP.NET 5 application through Atom editor?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, dnx

What are the most convenient ways to run your asp.net 5 application during coding in Atom editor ?

Is it possible to run `DNX run` command in Atom as it's working on Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: I googled "atom asp.net" and the first hit was a site dedicated to getting .NET working in multiple editors, including Atom. Did you try any basic research before asking your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DNX commands are supported in Atom via the OmniSharp plugin package.

See: https://atom.io/packages/omnisharp-atom